# Compare column names in excel sheet with column names in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have an excel sheet a large number of columns (~500) and a DB table with similar number of columns. I can run SQL queries on the database. What I want to achieve is to find the columns that are in my DB table but not in the spreadsheet. Checking it manually seems really inefficient.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking to write code that can do this? It would probably take less time to just compare manually if it's a one time job...

Comment: @Revent For the first part of this task I did a rather crude approach.  I opened the list of columns from the excel sheet as a comma separated list, copied the whole comma separated list and ran a SQL query keeping this in the select list. The columns that were not present gave errors. 
Now, I want to find the columns that are in the table but not in the excel sheet. A programming solution will be better, but what I am looking for is any type of hack that can do this job in a better way.

Comment: Should be able to use ADOX to query the structure of the table (or use regular ADO and query from the table using "... Where 1=0" so you just get the empty recordset).  You can then compare the sheet column headers and the recordset field names.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using ODBC functionality within excel? You should be able to open up the table in excel then use count formulas to ensure that the numbers match.

Answer (score 0):

You may try next semi-manual approach:

1. `select top 1 * from [your table]`
2. In **SSMS** right click to query results and select "*Copy with headers*"
3. Paste special->Transpose into Excel (pivot rows to columns)
4. Select headers in the existing excel, copy them, paste special-> transpose beside previous
5. Sort and compare columns